# Google analytic not working on android

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I have an android game, which I integrated with Google Analytics. I "think" my phone doesn't have google services installed, but documentation says that it should work. 
I have this in my manifesto

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
      dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false">

    </service>

    <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
         installation campaign reporting -->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

but I get the log message complaining that :

> AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.

And I don't get any hits on the console of google analytics.

Please help!